# How to recover deleted files in ubantu which is deleted by -delete comand?

Tags: data-recovery, django

While trying to reset my python Django project migrations due to 1st command my whole
is deleted.

How can I recover?

```
find . - path "*/migrations/*.py" -not -name " __init.py__ " -delete   **Wrong command

find . -path "*/migrations/*.py" -not -name " __init.py__ " -delete

find . -path "*/migrations/*.pyc" -delete
```

Comment: you can't, the data is gone. *IF* you lost a ton of files and turned off your PC immediately there is a *chance* a data recovery expert can get it, otherwise it's gone. There is no "recycle bin", `-delete` is permanent.

Comment: Stop using your computer immediately - the less you use it, the more files you have a chance of recovering.